# What is DbContext doing in ADO.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have code that make connection to the database and perform CRUD operations

Please see the code below:

We have in the code used "DbContext". 
Is it generic and can be used with all kinds of databases or is it made for SQLServer and what is its purpose/mission?

I thought DBContext was only used with the Entity Framework

```
public class UserRepository : Repository<User>
{
    private DbContext _context;
    public UserRepository(DbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }


    public IList<User> GetUsers()
    {
        using (var command = _context.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "exec [dbo].[uspGetUsers]";

            return this.ToList(command).ToList();
        }
    }

    public User CreateUser(User user)
    {
        using (var command = _context.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = "uspSignUp";

            command.Parameters.Add(command.CreateParameter("@pFirstName", user.FirstName));
            command.Parameters.Add(command.CreateParameter("@pLastName", user.LastName));
            command.Parameters.Add(command.CreateParameter("@pUserName", user.UserName));
            command.Parameters.Add(command.CreateParameter("@pPassword", user.Password));
            command.Parameters.Add(command.CreateParameter("@pEmail", user.Email));

            return this.ToList(command).FirstOrDefault();


        }

    }


    public User LoginUser(string id, string password)
    {
        using (var command = _context.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = "uspSignIn";

            command.Parameters.Add(command.CreateParameter("@pId", id));
            command.Parameters.Add(command.CreateParameter("@pPassword", password));

            return this.ToList(command).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }


    public User GetUserByUsernameOrEmail(string username, string email)
    {
        using (var command = _context.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = "uspGetUserByUsernameOrEmail";

            command.Parameters.Add(command.CreateParameter("@pUsername", username));
            command.Parameters.Add(command.CreateParameter("@pEmail", email));

            return this.ToList(command).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }


}
```

Here is DbContext class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DataAccessLayer
{
    public class DbContext
    {


        private readonly IDbConnection _connection;
        private readonly IConnectionFactory _connectionFactory;
        private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _rwLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
        private readonly LinkedList<AdoNetUnitOfWork> _uows = new LinkedList<AdoNetUnitOfWork>();

        public DbContext(IConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
        {
            _connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
            _connection = _connectionFactory.Create();
        }

        public IUnitOfWork CreateUnitOfWork()
        {
            var transaction = _connection.BeginTransaction();
            var uow = new AdoNetUnitOfWork(transaction, RemoveTransaction, RemoveTransaction);

            _rwLock.EnterWriteLock();
            _uows.AddLast(uow);
            _rwLock.ExitWriteLock();

            return uow;
        }

        public IDbCommand CreateCommand()
        {
            var cmd = _connection.CreateCommand();

            _rwLock.EnterReadLock();
            if (_uows.Count > 0)
                cmd.Transaction = _uows.First.Value.Transaction;
            _rwLock.ExitReadLock();

            return cmd;
        }

        private void RemoveTransaction(AdoNetUnitOfWork obj)
        {
            _rwLock.EnterWriteLock();
            _uows.Remove(obj);
            _rwLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _connection.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use EntityFramework to [execute raw SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx), but looks like `DbContext` in your example is not the one from EntityFramework. It can be some other library or custom implementation in your project. You should be able to tell that by examining `using` imports, or by navigating to the `DbContext` definition.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought DBContext was only used with the Entity Framework

You're right, DBContext is a EntityFramework class that combines unit of work and repository pattern.

However, you seem to have a custom DBContext created using ado.net. Though, I wouldn't really call it a DBContext. Since normally DBContext follows ObjectContext concept of referring to a domain object i.e. within a context. This particular custom class is more like a DbCommand factory.

> Is it generic and can be used with all kinds of databases or is it made for SQLServer[...]?

It's not SQL server specific. So it could be used with other databases like Oracle Database, Microsoft SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, and some others. But, that would depend on correct configuration and correct query usage for each database. For example, parameters are not always prefixed by `@` for all databases. But, this particular DBContext passes that problem on to the class that calls it and avoids dealing with it as we can see in UserRepository use of the class.

> ... and what is its purpose/mission?

The purpose of the DBContext you've shown us, is to get a connection using a factory, instantiate and return a DBCommand with an optional transaction. And, then the Repository base class function ToList seems to be in charge of executing the Command and mapping the objects User.

It looks like this was an attempt to create a repository pattern using ado.net. And, not knowing the history of your application, I can only assume there was a decision made to avoid using Entity Framework. There are many different ways I've seen this done. And, plenty of people will argue about the correct implementation. But, I think that would be out of the scope of this particular question.